# service waiting for a subscriber msg

Tags: ros, c++, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to have a Service server that upon request takes the next available camera image from the topic `/raw_image` and returns the position of a red blob. I would like to do this with a detector class, but I'm not sure how to do the conditoning: *when client request received than process the next available video frame and send the response*

My code so far:

```
class SwitchState_Detector
{
public:
    explicit SwitchState_Detector(ros::NodeHandle *nh);
    ~SwitchState_Detector();
    void image_callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &original_image);
    bool find_redBlob(cv::Mat input_image, cv::Mat output_image);
private:
    image_transport::Subscriber sub;
    cv::Mat I;                                       //OpeCV image
    std::string filename;                            //calibration file path
    cv::Mat *intrinsics;                             //camera intrinsics
    cv::Mat *distortion_coeff;                       //camera distortion coeffs
    cv::Size *image_size;  
}
SwitchState_Detector::SwitchState_Detector(ros::NodeHandle *nh) 
{
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    sub = it.subscribe("/image_raw", 1, &SwitchState_Detector::image_callback, this);
}

SwitchState_Detector::~SwitchState_Detector()
{
    delete intrinsics;
    delete distortion_coeff;
    delete image_size;
}

void
SwitchState_Detector::image_callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &original_image)
{
  //ROS Image to Mat structure
  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
  try
  {
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(original_image, enc::BGR8);
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("red_ball_detection::cv_bridge_exception %s", e.what());
    return;
  }
  I = cv_ptr->image;
    
   imshow("RGB", I);
   cv::waitKey(10);

}

double find_redBlob(cv::Mat input_image, cv::Mat output_image)
{
     // do the processing and calculations on Mat I received after the request was issued from a client
    // This Part I don't know how to condition that a fresh image was received.
return blob_size;
}

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "switch_state_detection");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  SwitchState_Detector detector(&nh);

  ros::ServiceServer service = nh.advertiseService("detect_switch_state", &SwitchState_Detector::find_redBlob, &detector);

  ros::spin();

  return(0);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217413/service-waiting-for-a-subscriber-msg/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Subscribe to a camera topic in your service, and as a callback store an image in a variable. Once the server receives a request, process the stored image.

---

Originally posted by [VitaliyProoks](https://answers.ros.org/users/882/vitaliyprooks/) with karma: 75 on 2015-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1